# g++, compilation problem overriding operator ostream << std::array with template

Tags: c++, g++, operator-overloading, c++-templates

I cannot compile with g++ a simple code that works perfectly in MSVC.

The code involves operator overload for ostream << array<T,D>, and g++ cannot find it, even though it's right here. Wherein the similar overload for ostream << vector doesn't cause any problem for g++.

A demo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

template <class T> inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, std::vector<T> &v) {
    const int D = v.size();
    os << "[";
    if (D > 0) os << v[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < D; i++) os << "," << v[i];
    os << "]";
    return os;
};

template <class T, int D> std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, std::array<T, D> &a) {
    os << "[";
    if (D > 0) os << a[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < D; i++) os << "," << a[i];
    os << "]";
    return os;
};


int main() {
    std::vector<double> v = {1,2,3,4};
    std::cout << v << std::endl;

    //std::array<double, 2> a = { 1,2 };            <-- this lines won't compile in g++
    //std::cout << a << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The commented lines cause g++ to spit a huge list of complains, starting with

```
test.cpp:33:12: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and 'std::array<double, 2>')
   33 |  std::cout << a << std::endl;
      |  ~~~~~~~~~ ^~ ~
      |       |       |
      |       |       std::array<double, 2>
      |       std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}
```

and ending with

```
ostream:691:5: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, std::basic_ostream<char>&>'
```

The g++ version is

```
g++.exe (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 9.2.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

The same story is with other operators, but I left only the essential part.

Why is that and how to solve?

I need the code compiled by g++, because in has __float128.
And I need the templates, because it's a part of generalized algorithm.

Please note that I'm new to C++.

I searched for similar cases but didn't any, at least not something helpful.

Comment: Please post the full set of errors.

Comment: Might not be relevant here, but your second parameter to the stream operator should be a _const_ reference.

Comment: and `// ...whatever` doesnt cause a compiler error. You should post that has the error not other code taht does not have the error ;)

Comment: Change `template <class T, int D>` to `template <class T, std::size_t D>`. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74727984/12002570) below.

Comment: To reviewers: technically speaking, the linked answer indeed contains the solution, but I would never see it if I weren't pointed to my mistake here. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The non-type template argument of `std::array` is of type `size_t` not `int`.

I am not sure which compiler is right here, but gcc accepts the code if you fix that:

```
template <class T, size_t D> std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, std::array<T, D> &a) {
    os << "[";
    if (D > 0) os << a[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < D; i++) os << "," << a[i];
    os << "]";
    return os;
};
```

[Complete Example](https://godbolt.org/z/7nd3xE1MY)

PS: Note that overloading `<<` for types you do not own comes with certain caveats. A function template `template <typename T,size_t D> void print(const std::array<T,D>&)` can do the printing as well.

Comment: I have found some non-official references that gcc is correct. But couldn't find the section in standard which states so.

Comment: @Karen what references?

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.2.0?topic=only-template-argument-deduction-c See the end.

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that the non-type parameter `D` in your overloaded version is of type `int` instead of `std::size_t`.

To **solve** this you can change the non-type parameter `D` to be of type `size_t` instead of `int` as shown below:

```
//-----------------vvvvvvvvvvv---->changed int to std::size_t
template <class T, std::size_t D> std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, std::array<T, D> &a) {
    os << "[";
    if (D > 0) os << a[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < D; i++) os << "," << a[i];
    os << "]";
    return os;
};


int main() {
   
    std::array<double, 2> a = { 1,2 };        
    std::cout << a << std::endl;  //works with all compiler now

    return 0;
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5o6eK6rx1)